# index of array changed inside ionic popup.then

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Here is my code after simplified:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {  //list.length == 2.
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'title',
        template: 'confirming message'
    });

    console.log(i); // i == 0, which is correct.
    confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            console.log(i); //i == 2, which is wrong, should be 0.
            list[i].property = true; //property of undefined error occur here. Because i is 2, list.length is 2, so there's no list[2] actually.
        }
        else {
            list[i].property = false; //same here.
        }
    });
}
```

So my issue is, I want to change `list[i].property` based on user's confirmation. But I don't know why the index changed from 0 to 2, I feel there's something to do with this `comfirmPopup.then`. Wondering how to fix this?

Comment: I'm curious as to what it is you're trying to achieve here. In what case would you need multiple subsequent pop-ups?

Comment: this list is phone numbers, each number has a toggle, user can only toggle one number. So whenever a toggle is enable, I check if other number is already toggled, if yes, the popup will show, ask user to choose one only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the nice solution:

Use list.forEach instead of for loop:

```
list.forEach(function (item) {
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'title',
        template: 'confirming message'
    });

    confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            item.property = true;
        }
        else {
            item.property = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood you correctly but take a look at the snippet below.

The issues you had were the following:

1. You said that you have a list of numbers. Is that an array of numbers, or an array of objects? If it was just an array of numbers, that would explain why you're getting undefined. See the snippet for how I set up the array.
2. The main problem you're having is that you're trying to use `i` after `confirmPopup.then(function (res) {`, but by then, `i` will already have been destroyed. The `res` in `confirmPopup.then(function (res) {` is basically the result of your popup selection. This means that if you select "OK", then it will try to insert the value of `i`, by which time the loop will have already been terminated.

Maybe this will help you.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
  
        var i = 0;
var list = [];
list = [{number: 123, property: false}, {number: 456, property: false}, {number: 678, property: true}];
   
var runPopUp = function() { 
 var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
    title: 'title',
    template: 'confirming message'
 });

 confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
  if (res) {
     list[i].property = true;
     alert(list[i].number + " = " + list[i].property);
     i++;
  }
  else {
     list[i].property = false;
     alert(list[i].number + " = " + list[i].property);
     i++;
  }
 })
}
   
$scope.toggle = function() {
 for (i; i < list.length; i++) {
  runPopUp();
 }
 i = 0;
} 
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/js/ionic.bundle.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    </ion-content>
     <div>
        123 is false; 456 is false; 678 is true;
         <button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-click="toggle()">Set Properties</button>
     </div>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to set the value based on users reaction, the popup has cancel/ok buttons, for example, if click ok, set list[i].property = true; if click cancel, set list[i].property = false. So I need a return value from the runPopup function, I tried it, didn't work..

Comment: Made some changes. Closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually now that I see it, looks similar to yours.

Comment: I got a nice solution from alumni, I post it below. Feel free to take a look :)